How to setup a windows Mobile 6.5 Emulator onto a Windows 10 Mobile Enterprise OS Honeywell CT50 Mobile Computer
Looking to use a Windows Mobile 6.5 Professional Emulator to operate on Windows 10 Mobile Enterprise. Trying to find compatibility to run software designed for windows mobile 6.5 to run from windows 10 mobile enterprise. Software being used on Win mobile 6.5 is required to be upgraded on a device capable of using 4G LTE network.
Trying to find compatibility to run software designed for windows mobile 6.5 to run from windows 10 mobile enterprise.

Are you saying you HAVE such an emulator, or that you are LOOKING for one?  Windows Mobile 6 ran the Windows CE kernel, which was radically different from the NT kernel in Windows 10 Mobile.  I hold little hope for your search.

I am currently in search for one. Or some sort of solution that would allow a program designed on windows 6.5 to function on a windows 8 or 10 mobile computer.

The two devices almost certainly have different processors, so the binaries will not run.  They would need to be emulated at an instruction level.  I'm not aware of any such thing.  You would need to recompile from source.
